# Printing environment variable inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shebang

Im trying to write simple shell script to parse a property file and compute another string based on those values.

**dev.properties**

```
com.global.jdbcUrl=${local_jdbcUrl}
```

**Environment variable**

```
export local_jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_0?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"
```

**bash file:**

```
#!/bin/bash

file="./dev.properties"

function prop {
  grep "${1}" ${file} | cut -d'=' -f2
}

text="global"
keys="jdbcUrl"

IFS=','
read -a strarr <<< "$text"
read -a keysarr <<< "$keys"

echo "There are ${#strarr[*]} words in the text.\n"
echo "There are ${#keysarr[*]} words in the text. \n\n"

for val in "${strarr[@]}";
do
  for refs in "${keysarr[@]}";
  do
    tmp="$val.$refs"
    printf "name : $tmp\n\n"

    valu="$(prop $tmp)"
    printf "value : $valu \n"

    printenv local_jdbcUrl
  done
done
```

Output of this script:

```
There are 1 words in the text.\n
There are 1 words in the text. \n\n
name : global.jdbcUrl

value : ${local_jdbcUrl} 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_0?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

I'm running migrations using shell script so to form a migration string command I need to have the actual environment variable value in a string. The environment variable substitution is not happening. Not sure what is wrong here. Can someone kindly help I'm new to bash script. I checked the environment value in the shell script and it's working fine, only inside the bash script I'm getting this error.

Comment: Are you trying to update `dev.properties` with the value of the variable?

Comment: @Fravadona I'm trying to compute a string value based on environment variable, something like `mysql --url=<environment_variable> value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `envsubst`

```sh
$ cat file
${HOME} is where the heart is

$ cat file | envsubst
/home/glennj is where the heart is
```